# C# logical streams not attached to files - possible?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have made a class that creates a `SortedDictionary` and fills it with roster information, keyed by date and employee number. In the form class where the roster object is created, I need to get access to the roster lines stored in the `SortedDictionary`, to either display them, or print them to a file.

Is it possible to create a method in my class that returns a `Stream` so that the calling function can more or less access the data in the `SortedDictionary` as if it were a file?

I looked at `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, however these require file names in their constructors. I am more or less thinking of a 'logical file' that is attached to the `SortedDictionary` and exposed as a stream that 'looks like' a file. The benefit of a stream, as I understand it, would be that the calling function would not need to know the structure of the `SortedDictionary`, it could just read until EOF, making it simple to use. Would a `MemoryStream` be applicable?

Comment: Why can't you access the data as a SortedDictionary?  You are describing a MemoryStream, but it's hard to tell if that is necessary based on your question.

Comment: @Harrison: yes I could expose the dictionary by making it public, however that would require the calling functions to have knowledge of the dictionary structure. My preference is the abstract that level of detail, and simply return a string that contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, `MemoryStream` would be the correct class to use.